# Dio data vs Dio query parameters

Tags: laravel, flutter, dio

I have implemented a login function in Laravel and I used `Dio` in flutter to send both email and password to it in the `data` parameter. But when checking values reaching the back-end, they were null. When I used `queryParameters` instead, they weren't null and the everything went successfully as expected. ALTHOUGH I alaways use the `data` parameter to send what I want to the Laravel back-end. What is the explanation of that?

This's the Laravel login function:

```
public function login(Request $request){
        try{
            $admin = Admin::where('email', $request->email)->first();
            if($admin == null){
                return Response([
                    'message' => 'This email address doesn\'t exist',
                ], 400);
            }
            else{
                if(Hash::check($request->password, $admin->password)){
                    return Response(200);
                }
                return Response([
                    'message' => 'The password is wrong, please check it & try again',
                ], 400);
            }
        }catch(Exception $exception){
            return Response([
                'message' => 'Something went wrong, please try again later',
            ], 500);
        }
    }
```

This's the flutter login function:

```
Future<Either<String, void>> adminLogin(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      print('Email: $email');
      print('Password: $password');
      await getIt<Dio>().get(
        APIs.ADMIN_LOGIN,
        queryParameters: {
          'email': email,
          'password': password,
        },
      );
      return Right(null);
    } on DioException catch (exception) {
      return Left(exception.getDioErrorMessage());
    }
  }
```